# Automatic casting with integer function parameter

Tags: php

With PHP 7 I just found out that if I have a function like this:

```
function automatic_int_conversion(int $value) {
    echo gettype($value) . ' ' . $value;
}
```

and I call it with a float parameter like this one:

```
automatic_int_conversion(2.0); # prints out: integer 2
```

the `float(2.0)` value is automatically converted to an int, while if I call the function with the `float(NAN)` this way:

```
automatic_int_conversion(NAN); # TypeError
```

I get a type error although the documentation says:

> As of PHP 7.0.0, instead of being undefined and platform-dependent, NaN and Infinity will always be zero when cast to integer.

IMHO this is pretty confusing and not consistent, because either every float is automatically converted or none.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: It prints "Notice: Undefined variable: x" https://3v4l.org/TpvFk but if we correct your error and remove your int cast it returns "double 2" https://3v4l.org/Bpv4Y

Comment: @BenM http://php.net/manual/en/math.constants.php or try `var_dump(NAN);`

Comment: @Andreas obviously `$x` was a copy-n-paster error. However the point here is the automatic cast, if I remove the typehint then there would be no question

Comment: It's not a typehint, you cast the value to integer. Here you cast it to string https://3v4l.org/BqvCv I don't understand what you actually are asking.

Comment: @Andreas read here http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration before talking

Comment: The question is about `NAN` not being a float (when cast), and not so much about the float being converted to an integer, right?

Comment: @chris85 the question is about why NAN, that is a float, is not automatically converted unlike other floats. In addition if you do `echo (int)NAN` you get 0 with no warning, notice or error.

Comment: I'm more surprised that the `2.0` just gets converted to an integer. I'd have thought since it isn't an `int` it would throw the same error. It's also strange that if you set it to a `float` the `NAN` comes back as a double.

Comment: I agree with you, in my option there should be no conversion at all. About double the doc says "Some references to the type "double" may remain in the manual. Consider double the same as float; the two names exist only for historic reasons."

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between type casting (explicit) and type coercion (implicit). The parameter value is not being cast to an int, it is being coerced. You can cast any value to int, e.g.:

```
echo (int) "a";  // prints 0
```

But passing "a" to your type declared function throws an error, just as passing NAN does:

```
automatic_int_conversion("a"); // TypeError
```

Coercion only works the same as casting on a very limited set of values.

You might want to enable strict types to disable the coercions for function parameters, then it will work 'as expected':

```
declare(strict_types=1);
```